# Execute this PHP outside of Magento

Tags: php, model, resource-model

I have some code I would like to be triggered outside of Magento but I continue to get an error. Here is the code:

```
<?php
// Part 1

require_once('store/app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

/**
     * Get the resource model
     */
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    /**
     * Retrieve the read connection
     */
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');



// Part 2

echo "Deleting 227";
// Delete base product
$id = '227';
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
foreach($items as $item):
if($item->getProduct()->getId() == $id):
$itemId = $item->getItemId();
$cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
break;
endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

I use Part 1 regularly in other PHP files. It seems I may be specifying the wrong model? The error I am getting:

**`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Response_Exception' with message 'Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /Users/root/Documents/webroot/pk3/redeem/upsell.php, line 21' in /Users/root/Documents/webroot/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:323 Stack trace: #0 /Users/root/Documents/webroot/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true) #1 /Users/root/Documents/webroot/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1246): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; char...') #2 /Users/root/Documents/webroot/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cookie.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse() #3 /Users/root/Documents/webroot/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cookie.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Cookie->_getResponse() #4 /Users/root/Documents/webroot/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cookie.php(260): Mage_Core_Model_Cookie->set('PHPSESSID', '64ad98a760b93cc in /Users/root/Documents/webroot/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php on line 323`**

Comment: Instead of using `echo`, try `Mage::app()->getResponse()->appendBody('Output here')`.  A "headers already sent" error is caused by sending output too early.

Comment: Thank you Don. I tried replacing echo with what you provided above but still get error. I technically was just using that echo line for debugging anyways so I dropped it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Another common culprit of "headers already sent" is extra whitespace at the start or end of your PHP file.  I'd say try getting rid of the closing PHP tag at the end of your code and check the start of it for whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Cleared of any and all white space/extra lines. Still a no go.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
         $quote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote")
                    ->load($quoteId);

             $product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($productId,$storeId=null,$identifierType = null);

                /** @var $quoteItem Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
                $quoteItem = $this->_getQuoteItemByProduct($quote, $productByItem,
                    $this->_getProductRequest($productItem));

                            $cartCandidates = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
                        ->prepareForCartAdvanced($requestInfo,
                                $product,
                                Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract::PROCESS_MODE_FULL
        );

        /**
         * Error message
         */
        if (is_string($cartCandidates)) {
            throw Mage::throwException($cartCandidates);
        }

        /**
         * If prepare process return one object
         */
        if (!is_array($cartCandidates)) {
            $cartCandidates = array($cartCandidates);
        }

        /** @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
        $item = null;
        foreach ($cartCandidates as $candidate) {
            if ($candidate->getParentProductId()) {
                continue;
            }

            $item = $quote->getItemByProduct($candidate);
        }

        if (is_null($item)) {
            $item = Mage::getModel("sales/quote_item");
        }

        if (!is_null($item->getId())) {

        $quote->removeItem($item->getId());
         $quote->collectTotals()->save();
        }
```